# A Function to Merge 100 Dataframes to one Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to programming and R is my first programming language to learn.

I want to merge 100 dataframes; each dataframe contains one column and 20 observations, as shown below:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(c(6,3,4,4,5,...))
df2 <- as.data.frame(c(2,2,3,5,10,...))
df3 <- as.data.frame(c(5,9,2,3,7,...))
...
df100 <- as.data.frame(c(4,10,5,9,8,...))
```

I tried using `df.list <- list(df1:df100)` to construct an overall dataframe for all of the dataframes but I am not sure if `df.list` merges all the columns from all the dataframes together in a table.

Can anyone tell me if I am right? And what do I need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/12993861 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136880/12993861

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine a list of data frames into one data frame by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851327/combine-a-list-of-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-by-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get all the objects into a `list` by specifying the `pattern` in 'ls' to check for object names that starts (`^`) with 'df' followed by one or mor digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string

```
df.list <- mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$'))
```

From the `list`, if we can want to `cbind` all the datasets, use `cbind` in `do.call`

```
out <- do.call(cbind, df.list)
```

---

NOTE: It is better not to create multiple objects in the global environment.  We could have read all the data into a `list` directly or constructed within a `list` i.e. if the files are read from `.csv`, get all the files with `.csv` from the directory of interest with `list.files`, then loop over the files in `lapply`, read them individually with `read.csv` and `cbind`

```
files <- list.files(path = 'path/to/your/location', 
         pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(files, read.csv))
```

Comment: Thanks! I do understand it's better not to create multiple objects in the global environment. I originally applied a for loop function to generate outputs from a dataset which are the dataframes I got in the global environment. But I then want to sum up all the outputs (dataframes) so I thought combining all these dataframes and sum them up together will be a solution. Is there any alternative method I can use to avoid creating these objects in the global environment whilst achieving the same result?

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `reduce` function from `purrr` package, after creating a character vector of names of data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

names <- paste0("df", 1:100)

names %>% 
  reduce(.init = get(names[1]), ~ bind_rows(..1, get(..2)))
```

Or in base R:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) rbind(x, get(y)), names, init = get(names[1]))
```